# Unit testing that functions of different dependencies are called in a specific order

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class that has 4 dependencies and one core function that calls a method from each dependency in a certain order. The function looks something like this:

```
Foo():
    A.a();
    B.b();
    C.c();
    D.d();
```

Function a must be called first. Then b. Then c. Then d.

How do I unit test this? I've read that you shouldn't mock more than 1 object in a single test.

Is my design flawed if I've gotten into a situation like this? I think I want to refractor to only have 3 dependencies, but it still doesn't solve my problem.

Also, a very general question about testing: my tests on this class feel a bit silly. I need to write a test to make sure that each function is called? Obviously a is called. Feels quite pointless writing the test.

I'm using c# and moq for mocking.

Comment: Why do you need to call them in a certain order? I think this is flawed unless there's a very good reason for it.

Comment: A connects. B sends. C commits. D checks progress after commit. A and b both use the same connection so I could join them, but C and D use different processes to do their work and there's no way around this

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really a unit test scenario. Sounds more like an integration test which should fulfill some higher level requirement like: it should be possible to make a transaction (or whatever your feature is).

Comment: If these operations must occur in the correct order, why not merge them into one method on one class?

Comment: It'd be quite a long method. And even when testing that single method id have to make sure the calls are done in the correct order

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of to test this using moq is to have a slightly convoluted series of callbacks.

something like this

```
bool aCalled = false;
bool bCalled = false;
bool cCalled = false;
bool dCalled = false;

Mock<A> mockA = new Mock<A>();
mockA.Setup(x => x.a())
       .Callback(aCalled=true);

Mock<B> mockB = new Mock<B>();
mockB.Setup(x => x.b())
       .Callback(if (aCalled){bCalled=true}else{Assert.Fail("B.b was called before A.a");

...etc for c and d
```

Comment: The art of unit testing says not to use more than 1 mock in a test. Any thoughts on that? Does it mean I have a bad design if I got into this situation?

Comment: I tend to be pragmatic about these things. As a rule only one mock per test is a good one, although you should be aware of the difference between a mock and a stub, as your tests may require more than 1 stub. In this case if your requirement is that certain calls are made in a specified order then I feel that having a test to verify that would be useful, and if the only way to verify that is to use more than 1 mock then I wouldn't be too worried. Rules of thumb are there to guide you and make you think when you break them. if you can justify the reason then I think you are ok.